# update jquery autocomplete as I type

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to use the jquery autocomplete on a dynamic field, so as I type, the search result is modified.

I am also getting the list from another file based on database selection. So basically if I type "hm", my SQL query should be updated to include like '%hm' and so forth.

Below is the code I am using - this just returns everything in the database and does not update the SQL query

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myterm').autocomplete({
      source: "meshauto-complete.php",
      matchContains: true, 
      minLength: 3, 
      delay: 300,  
      max: 10, 
      highlight: true ,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
      }

    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to revise the server side code to return the rows that match the typed input. The `meshauto-complete.php` will receive a `term` query string parameter which contains the text entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works fine now. I was not receiving the $_GET['term'] on the server side...so that was my confusion.